# Video tag on iOS is not working properly, video hides other elements

Tags: html, css, ios, html5-video, web-deployment

Newbie to web development. I'm trying to make a banner with a video background and some text overlay on the video. It works fine on Safari(macOS), Chrome(macOS) and Chrome(Android), but the video will hide all the text when using Safari(iPhone) and Chrome(iPhone) *** works fine on iPad though ***. Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong with my code? Thanks

```
<div class="container-fluid landing-banner">
   <div class="row banner-video-container">
       <video autoplay muted loop id="banner-video">
         <source src="https://mywebsite.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
       <h1>H1 text here</h1>
       <h2>H2 text here</h2>
       <a href="https://mywebsite.com/getstarted"><button class="btn-main">Get Started</button></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

..

```
div.landing-banner {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.banner-video-container {
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#banner-video {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.banner-video-container h1, .banner-video-container h2, .banner-video-container a {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your video to play 'inline' in the web page.

Try adding the playsinline attribute:

```html
<div class="container-fluid landing-banner">
   <div class="row banner-video-container">
       <video autoplay muted loop id="banner-video" playsinline>
         <source src="https://mywebsite.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
       <h1>H1 text here</h1>
       <h2>H2 text here</h2>
       <a href="https://mywebsite.com/getstarted"><button class="btn-main">Get Started</button></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

This should keep the video inline in the page. More info on iOS HTML5 for video here:

- https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/